# Sequence diagram: explicitly show websocket creation?

Tags: design, uml, modeling, sequence-diagram, middleware

I am trying to draw up a sequence diagram to show how my web client will interact with my backend over a websocket connection.

I am using a websocket middleware to manage the stream connections.

What is the best practice of sequence diagram in this case? Should I include the stream creation in it? Or it is simply showing too much low level information.

[image]

Comment: I would think that websocket creation would be an implementation detail, but hey, if you're going to show the stream creation as well ...

Comment: That's the bit I am not sure about: Should I include the middleware in the picture or not.

Comment: In general, you would show the level of detail that is most helpful to you, your project and your organization.  Here is an example: https://github.com/Ericsson/papyrus-patches/wiki/Sequence-Diagram-Implementation-Details

Comment: What level of granularity you show is dependent on what you are trying to communicate. Are you trying to illustrate how your software interacts with middleware? How the middleware works? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagram should fit **your** purpose.  The "best" practice therefore depend on your intentions and your focus:

- Is it a high-level design model to show the responsibilities of your core classes?  Then, focus on the core interactions between `Gamer` and `GameService`.
- Is it a detailed design for implementing a complex communication layer?  Then you may want to show all the objects that are actively involved in the interaction.
- Trivial low-level OS or OS-like services are not worth the diagramming effort:  would you add a file object to show to show that you save game results to the disk?  Would you add a GPU object to show that you're not really doing the drawings? Suche levell of detail would only clutter the diagrams which are not meant to be substitute for code.

I suspect the `Stream middleware` belongs to the last bullet and could be removed.  If you would nevertheless be in the second case, you should be consistent,  put the middleware in the middle and decompose  `GameStat update (via stream)` in two steps, so that the respectively responsibility of the middleware and the `Game service` is laid down without ambiguity.